# Different results when using string comparison and regexp in Hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, hiveql, impala

I have an Hive table with a date field in String format like the following

```
"2013-05-01 00:10:41.0"
```

I got inconsistent results between the following queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE mdate >= '2013-05-01' AND mdate <= '2013-05-31';

--> gives 111930


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE mdate regexp '^2013-05-\\d{2}.*';

--> gives 115038
```

Any clue on why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Gordon suggestion, however it does not respond the question and in this case there is no implicit conversion, you are comparing 2 strings. You are getting less values in the first comparison because you are letting out all the -31 values. You can run this to check ..

`select "2013-05-31 00:00:00.0" <= '2013-05-31' ;` -- false

`select "2013-05-30 00:00:00.0" <= '2013-05-31' ;` -- true

This is because you are doing a lexicographic compare ... and actually  `'2013-05-31'` is smaller than `"2013-05-31 00:00:00.0"`

If I would supposed about the less expensive way to perform this compare, I would say that it is substr and compare (regex are usually expensive and cast to date can be as well).

```
select substr("2013-05-31 00:00:00.0",1,10) <= '2013-05-31' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple:  do not use string functions unless the argument is a string.  You are trying to using string functions on dates, so `mdate` needs to be transformed into a string.  This is an implicit conversion, so it uses whatever system defaults are set on the system being used at that time.  In many databases, it can also have a big impact on performance.

Typically if you want all dates during May, you would use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE mdate >= '2013-05-01' AND mdate < '2013-06-01';
```

This works even if `mdate` has a time component.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not sure I ve understood your answer. The mdate field is already in string format (is not a date nor a timestamp) thus the conversion should not happen

Comment: @revy . . . You should be storing date/times using the appropriate data type.  If it is a string, you might still find that this works.